# Convert multiprocessing.Array to ctypes.c_void_p in Python

Tags: python, ctypes, python-multiprocessing

I need to convert a [multiprocessing.Array](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array) into a `c_void_p`. Currently this what I have:

```
shared_mem_bfr = multiprocessing.Array(c_uint8, img_width*img_height*3)
npyarr = np.frombuffer(shared_mem_bfr.get_obj(), c_uint8)
memory_buffer = npyarr.ctypes.data_as(c_void_p)
```

What bothers me is that I first convert it into a Numpy array and then into a c_void_p. Is there any way to remove the intermediate step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ctypes.addressof`:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import ctypes as c

shared_mem_bfr = mp.Array(c.c_uint8, 100)
print(c.c_void_p(c.addressof(shared_mem_bfr.get_obj())))

npyarr = np.frombuffer(shared_mem_bfr.get_obj(), c.c_uint8)
memory_buffer = npyarr.ctypes.data_as(c.c_void_p)
print(memory_buffer)
```

Output:

```
c_void_p(1552895115472)
c_void_p(1552895115472)
```